# How do I make a rule for my root htaccess to ignore the sub directory WordPress htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htaccess in my root file and it seems to be causing 403 errors for the pages that my wordpresses control.

```
#Redirects the default/home page
DirectoryIndex index.html
#

# Removes the html extention
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
#

#Rewrites psuedoblessings.com/Programming/* to psuedoblessings.com/programming/* And Redirects psuedoblessings.com/programming/ to psuedoblessings.com/Programming/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^programming/(.*) Programming/$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /Programming/
RewriteRule ^Programming/(.*) /programming/$1 [L,R=301]
#

#Rewrites psuedoblessings.com/Artistry/* to psuedoblessings.com/artistry/* And Redirects psuedoblessings.com/artistry/ to psuedoblessings.com/Artistry/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^artistry/(.*) Artistry/$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /Artistry/
RewriteRule ^Artistry/(.*) /artistry/$1 [L,R=301]
#
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php82” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

The wordpress htaccesses are within the subfolders root/Programming and root/Artistry.

```
# BEGIN Newfold Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Newfold-Cache-Level "2"
</IfModule>
# END Newfold Headers
# BEGIN Newfold Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END Newfold Browser Cache
# BEGIN Newfold Skip 404 Handling for Static Files
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|ads\.txt|[a-z0-9_\-]*sitemap[a-z0-9_\.\-]*\.(xml|xsl|html)(\.gz)?)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|avif|avifs|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|webp|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|webm|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
</IfModule>
# END Newfold Skip 404 Handling for Static Files

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
    Header set X-nginx-cache "WordPress"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /Artistry/DTC-355/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Artistry/DTC-355/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home4/wiossymy/public_html/Artistry/DTC-355/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home4/wiossymy/public_html/Artistry/DTC-355/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

I don't want to override the wordpress htaccesses with `RewriteOptions inherit` as I don't know if the rules in the root htaccess will break the pages even further.

I've tried adding `RewriteEngine On allow from all` to the two wordpress htaccess, but it didn't work.